# what does the"rpy" in URDF file means?

Tags: urdf, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.this is just a small part of the urdf file.actually i do not know the meaning of"rpy=0 0 1.57".what does rpy stand for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114776/what-does-the%22rpy%22-in-urdf-file-means?/) by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-01-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/71488/question-regarding-roll-pitch-yaw-and-coordinate-system/) might give you a good insight about `roll`, `pitch`, `yaw` in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on 2014-01-06**:
THANK  YOU.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some hints after doing this recently:

Roll is applied first about the X-axis of the previous joint. The frame you're modifying will rotate X radians about the previous X-axis.

Pitch is applied next about the Y-axis of the previous joint.
Yaw is applied last about the Z-axis of the previous joint.

Each rotation seems to be capped at pi radians. For example, if you enter a pitch of 3.9 radians, the actual rotation you see will only be pi radians.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4